# complex Query Builder in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have a raw query that's look like this and have to transform in query builder in Laravel 5.5 without using eloquent and need to have pagination

```
select lt.country_name, u.user_id, u.real_name from users u
join lang_table lt on lt.language_id = u.country
where not exists (select fr2 from friends where fr1 = 1 and fr2 = u.user_id and status = 1) and not exists(select fr1 from friends where fr2 = 1 and fr1 = u.user_id and status = 1) 
and u.user_id <> 1
and u.country = 1
```

trying a lot of variants like this below but every time give me an error
if someone can help me?

```
$data = DB::table('users')
               ->join('lang_table','lang_table.language_id', '=' ,'users.country')
             ->select('lang_table.country','users.user_id','users.real_name')
               ->select(DB::raw(where not exists (select fr2 from friends where fr1 = 1 and fr2 = u.user_id and status = 1) and not exists(select fr1 from friends where fr2 = 1 and fr1 = u.user_id and status = 1) 
and u.user_id <> 1
and u.country = 1))
               ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: SQLSTATE[4200]:Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Comment: I think that the problem come from the not exist clause because in query builder doesn't have analog of this command I think and the DB::raw doesn't accepted for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try to change strict to false in config\database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write this request and now gives me the following error

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\findfriends\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill‌​uminate\Database\Con‌​nection.php on line 665

```
DB::select(`lt.country_name`,`u.user_id`,`u.real_name`)
        ->from(`users as u`)
        ->join(`lang_table as lt`, function($join) {
            $join->on(`lt.language_id`, `=`, `u.country`);
            })
        ->whereRaw(`not exists`, [], `( select fr2 from friends where fr1 = 1 and fr2 = u.user_id and status = 1 )`)
        ->whereRaw(`not exists ( select fr1 from friends where fr2 = 1 and fr1 = u.user_id and status = 1 )`, [], `and`)
        ->where(`u.user_id`, `<>`, 1)
        ->where(`u.country`, `=`, 1)
        ->paginate(25);
```